# `org-publish` export utf-8 symbols instead of html entities

Tags: org-export, html, org-publish

Can we make `org-publish` export quotes `""` as literal uni-code symbols instead of html entities such as `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `C-h v org-entities` and `C-h v org-entities-user`. You can override the `ldquo` and `rdquo` entries in the first one by supplying modified entries for the second one.

E.g. `org-entities` says:

```el
 ...
 ("ldquo" "\\textquotedblleft{}" nil "&ldquo;" "\"" "\"" "“")
 ("rdquo" "\\textquotedblright{}" nil "&rdquo;" "\"" "\"" "”")
 ...
```

So, assuming that `org-entities-user` is `nil` (as it is by default), you can override those entries with:

```el
(setq org-entities-user
 '(("ldquo" "\\textquotedblleft{}" nil "“" "\"" "\"" "“")
   ("rdquo" "\\textquotedblright{}" nil "”" "\"" "\"" "”")))
```

where I have replaced the HTML entity entries with the UTF-8 ones.

Untested. I'm not sure whether there should be a string entry as well (see the value of `org-entities` and look for  `"** Quotations"`); I don't know what these string entries are used for.